# Microsoft CRM 2011 on premise cross domain authentication failing

Tags: wcf, dynamics-crm-2011, crm, microsoft-dynamics

I have a CRM 2011 on premise installation on one domain and have a web server (server 2008) on a seperate domain with the web server hosting an MVC 3 website that is trying to access the services published on the CRM server.

I am using an early bound entity class created by running CrmSvcUtil.

My problem is when I try and use the services from code on the web server I receive a "The request for security token could not be satisfied because authentication failed" exception.

If my CRM install is on premise is it actually possible to connect from another machine on a seperate domain without CRM being installed as IFD?

I am using credentials to call the services...

```
public override bool ValidateUser(string username, string password)
    {
        var credentials = SecurityHelper.BuildClientCredentials(_crmUsername, _crmPassword, _domain);


        using (_serviceProxy = new OrganizationServiceProxy(new Uri(_organisationUri), null, credentials, null))
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(username) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
            {
                _serviceProxy.EnableProxyTypes();


                using (var orgContext = new XrmServiceContext(_serviceProxy))
                {......
```

And my helper class to create the credentials.....

```
public class SecurityHelper
{
public static ClientCredentials BuildClientCredentials(string username, string password, string domain)
    {
        var credentials = new ClientCredentials();
        credentials.Windows.ClientCredential = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(username, password, domain);
        credentials.UserName.UserName = username;
        credentials.UserName.Password = password;
        return credentials;
    }
}
```

In terms of the application pool as the web server is on a different domain can I apply a user account from the CRM box?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should be able to do this. Is the user running the app pool of your MVC site a user in CRM? Or are you providing credentials for the calls to CRM?

Answer (score 0):

We've been having the exact same issue. If we create a service via proxy it simply doesn't work.

However, you can get this to work if you pass in the IOrganizationService reference inside the localContext and use that instead of the proxy approach.

Afaik, the intent of the proxy creation is when you connect to CRM outside the application. When inside a plugin, microsoft gives you all the object references required to crud.

(Has anyone been able to create a service proxy inside a plugin and actually have it work????)